# VPN between iPad and SonicWALL Pro 2040 firewall

Tags: vpn, sonicwall, ipad

We have a SonicWALL Pro 2040 firewall at our office, and we want a user to be able to use his iPad to connect to it over a VPN. Is this possible? Has anyone actually done it with this exact model of firewall? Which version of the SonicOS is required?

Comment: It is supposed to work, but you might get into trouble. Please have a look at [this related post](http://serverfault.com/questions/253291/error-connecting-to-sonicwall-l2tp-vpn-from-ipad-iphone/253303#253303).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Sonicwall KB for setting up a L2TP VPN](http://www.sonicwall.com/us/support/2213.html?kbid=3544). I might suggest creating a new VPN zone if you're already using the Global VPN client.

Also if you have issues connecting with your Ipsec (Phase 2). Change the `Encryption` from `3DES` to `DES`. I've had to do that on both Android devices as well as a few iPads and iPhones.

[Here is the link for setting up the iPad](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8165.html)

Comment: I believe [this](http://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=6579) is the link for setting up the iPad.