# PFsense VPN all types failing?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, pfsense, pptp, l2tp

I am trying to configure a new PFsense router (64 bit) and am trying to to get the VPN functions working.

I have enabled PPTP, L2TP and IPSec. I've added allow all rules to all LAN's, WAN's and each of the VPN types while I test it.

**L2TP Raw Logs**
    l2tps: process 25991 started, version 4.4.1 (root@FreeBSD_8.0_pfSense_2.0-AMD64.snaps.pfsense.org 13:49 11-Aug-2011)
    l2tps: Label 'startup' not found
    l2tps: [l2tp0] using interface l2tp0
    l2tps: L2TP: waiting for connection on 0.0.0.0 1701

**PPTP Raw Logs**
    pptps: process 60043 started, version 4.4.1 (root@FreeBSD_8.0_pfSense_2.0-AMD64.snaps.pfsense.org 13:49 11-Aug-2011)
    pptps: Label 'startup' not found
    pptps: PPTP: waiting for connection on 0.0.0.0
    pptps: [pt0] using interface pptpd0

**IPSec Raw Logs**
    racoon: [94.197.127.20] ERROR: exchange Identity Protection not allowed in any applicable rmconf.

I can't see to connect to any of them using my test device (iPhone 5). They iPhone just says connecting and then eventually fails saying the remote server did not respond.

Is this a known issue or am I missing something obvious?

**Additional Settings**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I had faced an exact same issue about a month ago...I read some where on pfsense forum that its the 64 bit version which has a issue, I then installed 32 bit pfsense and all waswell. Give that a go n see if that works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iThingies are picky about what exactly they need when it comes to VPN. The problem is basically, the defaults most VPN servers use for IPSec is too *insecure* for iThingies.

Has some good tips: [Error connecting to Sonicwall L2TP VPN from iPad/iPhone](https://serverfault.com/questions/253291/error-connecting-to-sonicwall-l2tp-vpn-from-ipad-iphone)

I had a very similar problem getting iThingies to talk to a SonicWall, and had to make some significant changes that made that particular VPN setup not work for anything BUT iThingies.

Specifically, the IKE proposals need to be modified to be something iOS supports. A list can be found [here](http://o-www.sonicwall.com/us/en/support/2213.html?kbid=3544), but for posterity:

**Phase 1 transforms**

- All pre-shared key
- AES-256 encryption / SHA1 or MD5 authentication / Diffie-Hellman Group 2
- AES-128 encryption / SHA1 or MD5 authentication / Diffie-Hellman Group 2
- 3DES encryption / SHA1 authentication / Diffie-Hellman Group 2

**Phase 2 transforms**

- AES256 encryption / SHA1 or MD5 authentication
- AES128 / SHA1 or MD5
- 3DES / SHA1 or MD5

iOS3 is even more restrictive.

Comment: the defaults in pfSense match what iOS requires. Some other things do default to "too-insecure-for-iOS" options but not us.

Comment: From what I've read the setting I have should work on iOS and Windows/Mac workstations. I'll give the above alterations a try though.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see from your logs, the only error you're getting is the latter, IPSec, which is likely because the iPhone wants Main Mode not Aggressive Mode for IKE.  The other "errors", well, it looks like the pfSense hasn't received a request yet for PPTP or L2TP.

Are you connecting with 3G/4G/LTE?  Could very well be a limitation from your service provider if you're not receiving any traffic.

I would suggest doing a packet capture on the WAN interface to confirm that you are receiving packets.  Also, try with a wifi connection, see if you get the same results.

Comment: The iPhone can connect to a PPTP and L2TP VPN running on a Draytek Vigor using default settings. It's connecting over 3G both times.

Answer (score 1):

The L2TP is strictly L2TP, not L2TP+IPsec which is what iOS requires. L2TP+IPsec is not supported in pfSense at this time.

PPTP and IPsec will both work no problem with iOS. IPsec is more complex but not all that hard. 
http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Mobile_IPsec_on_2.0

PPTP is basically impossible to not configure correctly. The fact it doesn't work suggests you either have basic WAN-side connectivity problems, or are using a 3G/4G carrier whose CGNAT doesn't pass GRE, which is common in many places and means PPTP cannot function on that 3G/4G network. IPsec has no such issues.

Comment: I've added screenshots of my WAN settings, can you see anything blindingly obviously wrong?